# Minecraft PVP Minigame Help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to make a pvp minigame.

I have all the teams worked out, and I want the game to start when all the players are in the game. Because at the moment one player can join the game and loot everything before all the other players have joined is there any way I can stop this?

Comment: Have you looked at how existing minigames do this sort of stuff?

Answer (score 1):

Teleport everyone at the same time using **/tp @a[team=(Color)] x y z** so you can teleport different teams to different places.

Comment: Just click the tick underneath the number 0 with the arrows with tell them that you like there answer and it works.

Comment: What do i do for (Colour)-

Comment: If you have a team called Lolcatz and there colour was red and you had another team called Toilets and there colour was yellow you would do /tp @a[team=yellow] 0 0 0 and the would tp the Toilets and /tp @a[team=red] 0 0 0 that would tp all the people in team Lolcatz

Comment: I did this but it still won't work /tp @a[team=(red)] -621 80 428

Comment: You have to do it without the brackets around the colour so just /tp @a[team=red] -621 80 428 the brackets mean whatever colour they don't actually have to be there